# TypeError: (node.text || []).map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

This is the final result which i obtained in mapping state i want to map the text array inside node state please Ignore the nodes const it is the output which i got in the console.log(this.state.nodes);

```
     `const nodes = [{
             id: 1,
             style: 'dummy data',
             className: 'dummy data',
             text: [
              { id: 1, text: 'text 1'},
              { id: 2, text: 'text 2'}
             ]
           }]`
```

Here i map the node state i have text array in node State i want to access text 1 inside text how can i achieve this by mapping

```
   `{this.state.nodes.map((node, index) => {
            const showbutton = node.className === 'square';
            const decisionbutton = node.className === 'diamond';

     return(
      <div
             key={index}
             className={'node ' + node.className}
             id={node.id}
             ref={nodes => this.refs.nodes[index] = nodes}
             style={node.style}
             onClick={this.activeElem}

         >
           {(node.text|| []).map((child,key)=>{
             return (
                <div key={key}>
                {child.text}
                </div>
             );
           })}`
```

Comment: what is `node.text`?

Comment: it's one of his `state` variabels

Comment: yes it is my variable inside nodes state

Comment: let me show you the console of mine state

Comment: yess its an array inside node state

Comment: This is mine screenshot of my nodes state map as node

https://gyazo.com/6547a7b0af43ccc5ffdd7ee13528daf6

Comment: remove the `\`` first `...})}\``

Comment: @SASSY_ROG  check the above screenshot brother

Comment: I am using this because i want to make a dynamic form

Comment: Can you share the whole component code, as much as possible? When/where are `state.nodes` initialized/created would help answer this question.

Comment: @Asad `node.text` must give you something other then an Array. have you checked to see what are you getting there? (plain console or typeof)?

Comment: its giving me [object][object]

Comment: @Asad that's the problem. `map()` is a a function for an Array. you got a js object. Try doing `JSON.stringify(node.text)` and see what are you getting on console

Comment: Only one time i am getting undefined

Comment: @FedeSc i am getting undefined when i am console.log(JSON.stringify(node.text.text))

but when i am trying to do node.text i got ["
text"] which i entered

Comment: @Asad based on your comments i've written an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue with `map` inside the rxjs html
Here's my work around it...

```js
 return(
      <div
             key={index}
             className={'node ' + node.className}
             id={node.id}
             ref={nodes => this.refs.nodes[index] = nodes}
             style={node.style}
             onClick={this.activeElem}

         >
           {Array.from(Array(node.text.length), (e, i) => {
                return (
                        <div key={key}>
                         {node.text[i].text}
                        </div>
                       )
           }
      </div>
)
```

see if it helps.
I'm just creating a temp empty array and using it's index to iterate over the `node.text` array

Comment: check this bro its giving me undefined

Comment: This is my code for the node mapping and text



    ` {this.state.nodes.map((node, index) => { 
     {Array.from(Array(node.text.length), (e, i) => {
                   return (
                          <div key={i}>
                          {console.log(node.text[i].text)}
                          {node.text[i].text}
                         </div>
                        )
             })}`

Comment: If you have three items in node.text, do you get the `undefined` 3 times on the console?

Comment: @SASSY_ROG The problem is really applying `map()` on a javasript object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first variable in condition `(node.text || [])`, isn't really an `Array`.

When you tried to console it, it showed you `[object][object]`. 
which is a JS `Object`data type - And `map()`, is a function that exists in `Array.prototype`.

When you did `console.log(JSON.stringify(node.text))` it did show you the text as inteded.

`.map()` won't work on `undefined` also.

That's the reason it's failing. `node.text` isn't an array.

If you return a object, consider using `Object.keys` ([info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) to loop through it, or a `for...of` loop,
or just reformat `node.text` to be of type array.

Comment: Yeah i understand the problem but i am still trying to figuring out how can i show it in nodes

Comment: @Asad Change the object to an array (manipulate it before arriving to that mapping point) or change your map function to a function that deals with objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
const nodes = [{
             id: 1,
             style: 'dummy data',
             className: 'dummy data',
             text: [
              { id: 1, text: 'text 1'},
              { id: 2, text: 'text 2'}
             ]
           }]

node.map((node) => { return node.text.map((value) => (value.id)); })
```

running this, it returns the valid values... just make sure that the node.text has object as values rather then string as shown in the [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/6547a7b0af43ccc5ffdd7ee13528daf6)